# Unity: Способ копировать префабы из одного проекта в другой?

Tags: unity3d

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. При копировании префаба он, фактически нерабочий.

Есть ли возможность скопировать все нужные файлы (материал, нужные скрипты, другие кастомные компоненты) так что бы с минимальным гемором возможно было перенести в другой проэкт?

То ли экспортонуть в ассет, то ли еще что.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ оказался прост.

Assets -> Export Package

и выбрать нужные файлы + не снимать галочку "подтягивать зависимости"